# Calling overridden method in multiple derived ViewModels

Tags: c#, xamarin, inheritance, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm struggling with a somehow unusual Mvvm implementation. I have a multi-page app where I need to access some properties in multiple views and make sure changes in one view are updated in all of them. I try to achieve this by the following implementation:

```
public class BaseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string SharedProperty
    {
        get=>BaseModel.sharedProperty;
        set
        {
            if(CustomSet(ref BaseModel.sharedProperty, value, SharedRaise))
                ReloadStuff();
        }
    }
    public abstract void ReloadStuff();
    public void SharedRaise(string caller) => RaisePropertyChanged(caller);
    private bool CustomSet<T>(ref T prop, T value, Action<string> raise, [CallerMemberName] string caller)
    {
        if ((prop == null && value == null) || (prop != null && prop.Equals(value)))
            return false;

        prop = value;
        raise.Invoke(caller);

        return true;
    }
    public static class BaseModel
    {
        public static string sharedProperty;
    }
}

public class Child1ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string someData;
    public string SomeData
    {
        get=>someData;
        set=>Set(ref someData, value);
    }
    public override void ReloadStuff()
    {
        SomeData = GetNewData();
    }
}

public class Child2ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string someOtherData;
    public string SomeOtherData
    {
        get=>someData;
        set=>Set(ref someOtherData, value);
    }
    public override void ReloadStuff() { } //Do nothing, better would be to remove the overriden method in Child2ViewModel at all
}
```

The desired behavior should be as followed:

When changing the property SharedProperty from Child2View, the method RaisePropertyChanged ("SharedProperty") should be called on any active instance derived from BaseViewModel. Also, every overridden method of ReloadStuff() in any instance derived from BaseViewModel should be called.

Sadly for now, this does not work, but for now, I hope that I only miss something, rather than all of this is rubbish. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, what you are saying is broken in an Object-oriented sense because how would one object know what another object did unless the first one is manually made aware of the same? Secondly, even if you notify on property change you need to understand that it is for that particular instance not all of them. Now to make all of them aware of it is only possible if you store all these values at one place and then all your view models reference this something like a god object! or [Messaging Center](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/xamarin-forms-messagingcenter-ab97eb923fd0) is an option to notify views.

Comment: by putting all the shared private-values into a static class, I was hoping to make them available across all view models.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Messaging Center looks like a valid solution for my problem. Not what I was looking for, but at least the same result.

Comment: Happy to help let me know in case if you need anything